# How to pass data from one JComboBox to an SQL statement that will terming the values of the second JComboBox?

Tags: java, database, swing, prepared-statement, jcombobox

```
private void fillCombo(){
    try {
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MTD","root","");
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("Select * from sa where municipalities ='"  + municipality.getSelectedItem().toString()+ "'");
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()){
            String mun = rs.getString("Province");
            municipality.addItem(mun);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
```

I have two combo boxes that get values from the database. The first combo (`province`) comes from a table with one column which is a list of provinces. So on `province.itemchangedstate` I want it to set the values of `combo2` (`municipalities`) in relation to the province selected by `combo1` (`province`).

Am new to java and stuck on that and don't know how to proceed further. Can anyone help?

Comment: *"Am new to java and stuck on that and don't know how to proceed further."*  Stuck on what, specifically?  As it stands, this question is either 'unclear what you are asking' or 'too broad'.  Please narrow it down, show what you've tried, and ask a more specific question.

Comment: @Andrew i have only managed to populate the first combo to get the list of provinces. I now want to pass the value of the user select province to an sql query which will populate the second combo with only municipalities that fall within a given user selected province.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).  Hard code some data to replace the DB (say 2 provinces with 3 municipalities each should do it).

Comment: assuming that on the 1st combo a user select province a, a should then be passed to an sql query ( select all from table where province=a). the results of the query should then populate combo 2

Comment: .. Why are you repeating that?  I'll repeat, replace the DB parts and post an MCVE.

Comment: Separate the SQL from the GUI.  Read all of the provinces and **all of the municipalities** from the database before you create and show the GUI.  Show the municipalities from the selected province from a Map.

Comment: @Gilbert the idea is that when the form loads the should be  default values for example Province(Gaugeng) Municipalities(Tshwane Metro,JHB Metro, Erkhuleni) this i have done already the challenge come when a user selects a different province on which actionlister do i need to put in the query that will dynamically populate the second combo based on the choices of the first combo.

Comment: @Herb21: Not if you've already read all of the municipalities.  Do you really want your user waiting 3 seconds for an SQL query to execute before you can populate the second JComboBox?

Answer (score 1):

According to me,your requirement is to populate one combobox on the basis of selection of other.
like
[image]

might be this sample code work for you.

```
private void populateDropDownOfEnum(){
        EncDecImageFrame encDecImageFrame = new EncDecImageFrame();

        jComboBox1.setEditable(true);
        String[] jComboBox1Values = getListOfAllEnumNames();
        if (jComboBox1Values != null && jComboBox1Values.length != 0) {
            jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(jComboBox1Values));
        }

        Object item = jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
        jComboBox2.removeAllItems();
        jComboBox2.setEditable(true);
        String[] enumValuesByEnumNames = getListOfAllEnumValues(
                item.toString(), artifcatoryPathOfJar.getText());
        jComboBox2.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(
                enumValuesByEnumNames));

        jComboBox1.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                Object item = jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
                jComboBox2.removeAllItems();
                jComboBox2.setEditable(true);
                String[] enumValuesByEnumNames = getListOfAllEnumValues(
                        item.toString(), artifcatoryPathOfJar.getText());
                jComboBox2.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(
                        enumValuesByEnumNames));

            }
        });
```

Comment: How showed i modify the code to select the values from a database